# Randomly generate those Shapes

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, haxe

I'm looking for a way to draw draw/generate those shapes you can see on the image below in AS3/Haxe (OpenFL). Possibliy without any external images.

[image: Screenshot from this Video: www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_aOIA-vyBo]

[Image Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_aOIA-vyBo)

This is what I got so far: [Version 2](http://vps.deesr.com/DrawShapes2.swf) ([Source](http://cl.ly/code/140S3W261g1w))

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these shapes are made up of rectangles with rounded edges of different lengths.

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawRoundRect()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawRoundRect%28%29)

Here is how to get one:

```
var rect:Shape = new Shape();
rect.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x00ff00, 1); //Last arg is the alpha
rect.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1); //Last arg is the alpha
rect.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 25, 25)
rect.graphics.endFill();
addChild(rect);
```

You'll need to randomize the x, y. You can get a random number from n+-10 or so for x and n+5 or so for y.

Then do similarly for length and height.

Create about 5 of these rounded rects and see how you do.

If you try something like that and post the results we can work on the next step of connecting them.

Comment: Because rounded rectangles must be connected with each other, and the connection is again a rounded one, you MUST draw 'connecting' rectangles with negative rounding :)

Comment: Okay, this is what I came up with so far: http://vps.deesr.com/DrawShapes.swf
(Click to generate new Shape).

Now comes the hard part, connecting those rectangles ;)

Comment: Wonderful! It looks like you have the images, and the connections between them. To be more accurate, it looks like your variance for width is a little too large. Try reducing your random +- on the length for each rect.

What else would you like to do with your 2nd version to improve it?

Comment: There're two things that are still missing, compared to the original image: 1.) That's is possible that there 2 Rectangles next to each other (which I could do by my own i hope). 2.) That There are multiple diffrent sized Rectangles over each other, but the empty spaces are filled out. I have no clue how I could achieve that...

Comment: Can you please post your code so far? I can help you get multiple sets of these images on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Added the current source code to the my question. I'm sure it's not the best way to achieve this, but I'm open for suggestions ;)

Comment: I see your class code, but to help you to create multiple instances of that graphic, as per you request #2, I'd need to see how the class is implemented.

Comment: Just stage.addChild(new Cloud());

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear on what you still want then.